# Is the comparison "There are no people in this room as in that room." ambiguous?

Tags: ambiguity

> There are no people in this room as in that room.

Out of context, I want to know if this structure is ambiguous. Can "As in that room" be read as either:

- there are people in that room
- there are no people in that room

Comment: You text isn't idiomatically valid. I could *guess* that it means *There are no people in this room **just as there are no people** in that room*, but no native speaker would ever say your version, and mine is very "unlikely". But is that the meaning you're trying to convey?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I had initially intended to convey the first idea, however, I suddenly realized that there might be a possibility of it being misinterpreted as the second notion. This led to my inquiry regarding the ambiguity.  Thanks for telling me that a native speaker wouldn't say that version at all.

Comment: Old Mother Hubbard looked in the cupboard for a bone for her dog, but there was no bone in the cupboard. So she looked in the bin, but ***as in the cupboard**, there was no bone.* That's just about valid English (though I'd prefer ***with*** rather than ***in***), but it's not something anyone would be likely to say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what you mean, and I don't think an English speaker would say that at all.

1. If you're comparing this room (with no people) and that room (with people) you might say something like this:

- there are no people in this room, **by contrast with** that room.
- there are people in that room, **but not in** this room.

2. If you're comparing this room (with no people) and that room (also with no people) you might say:

- there are no people in this room **or** that room.

3. If you are using **as** with the meaning **just as** or **in the same way that**, then you are right that your example is ambiguous. Suppose you wrote, "There are no people in this room, **as is the case** in that room." I would *guess* that there are people in that room, but I would be rather unsure of myself.

No doubt there are other possibilities, but hopefully this will get you started.